# FullCalenday Clicking Day change to Agenda View of that particular date

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fullcalendar

I am showing the month view in the Full Calendar. When i click a day in the month view it should display the Day/Agenda View for that particular day.

Below is the code - But it shows the present days agenda view instead the one clicked.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

      if (allDay) {
        // Clicked on the entire day
        $('#calendar')
        .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay'/* or 'basicDay' */)
        .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
      }

    },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is how i do that exact thing:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  if(view.name == 'month' || view.name == 'basicWeek') {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);      
  }
}
```

*code edit*

Comment: changing the order gotoDate and ChangeView got it working for me on my code

Answer (score 4):

For the **version 4** is like this:

```
dateClick: function(info) {
    if(info.view.type=="dayGridMonth"){
        this.changeView("timeGridDay",info.dateStr);
    }
  }
```